# Code not exiting while loop (trying to catch exceptions)

Tags: java, exception, do-while

I have written the very simple code (n1 / n2 = sum) whilst trying to learn try / catch exception handling.

I have a do / while loop which is supposed to make x = 2 when run successfully. If not, x = 1, where the user input can be entered again.

The code compiles and runs but if I try, for example n1 = 10, n2 = stackoverflow, the prinln from the caught exception runs forever!

Why is the loop stuck?

Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExceptionHandlingMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = 1; // x originally set to 1
        do { // start of do loop
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter numerator: ");
                int n1 = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter divisor");
                int n2 = input.nextInt();

                int sum = n1 / n2;

                System.out.println(n1 + " divided by " + n2 + " = " + sum);
                x = 2; 
// when the code is completed successfully, x = 2 and do / while loop exits

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("You made a mistake, moron!");
            }
        } while (x == 1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: When handling the exception, you should probably clear the `Scanner` object.

Comment: Thanks barak. What do you mean by 'clear the scanner object'?

Comment: I mean, reset this object. See the answer to the question I pointed above (or the two answers below, which give the same solution as the answer to that other question).

Comment: @mikeeustace - See, the wrong input you entered will be present in the inputstream from which the scanner instance reads. You have to move your scanner pointer past that input to read next input. Else you will keep reading the same input / line (that is the problem here)\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `input.nextLine()` in your `catch` block to clear the line read.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are pressing return key post entering the number.

I would suggest you add `input.nextLine();` call, so you consume return key as well after reading your input from Scanner.

So with `nextInt` api, when you type like:

```
 123<return key>
```

`nextInt` will just pick up 123 as a string and convert that to a number and leave return key part as is.

Comment: The solution is right, but your explanation is wrong. The issue occurs when the user enter either for the `numerator` or `divisor` `stackoverflow+ENTER` the `Iinput.nextInt()` throws an `InputMismatchException` and leaves `stackoverflow` as next input value. As the input is not removed in the catch block it stays there and the next `Iinput.nextInt()` will throw again an `InputMismatchException` and leaves .... and so on. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @barak manos (and others who replied)

adding

```
input.nextLine();
```

immediately after

```
System.out.println("You made a mistake, moron!");
```

clears the input stream and allows the user to enter new data.

cite: 
Answer adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24414457/4440127
User: user3580294